# PHP files on local server - Upgraded Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, ubuntu, drupal

Hello I just upgraded Ubuntu to 16.04 and now I have a problem with all my Drupal sites and php files installed locally. If I type localhost/"drupalsite" on my browser, it just shows the content of the index.php file. This happens with Drupal 7 sites as well as with Drupal 8 sites. Sites in html inside localhost are being shown without a problem. Php5 has been deleted and I can't install it again (maybe there's the problem).

"El paquete php5 no está disponible, pero algún otro paquete hace referencia a él" -->
"The package libapache2-mod-php5 isn't available, but some other package references it"

Does anybody have a clue please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 16.04 has switched to PHP 7.0 with a new infrastructure for PHP package. So, no, you can't install php5 on Ubuntu 16.04, but you can install PHP 7.0 packages with:

```
apt-get install libapache2-mod-php
```

that will install a virtual package that depends on the latest PHP version and pull libapache2-mod-php7.0 as a dependency.

Comment: Thank you @Anoop saju for the help. It apparently took me a step forward. I get following error now:  http://paste.ubuntu.com/16021144/